# How can I remove pagenumber at left and contents at right from Header , from page after \tableofcontents page

Tags: table-of-contents

I am creating a chapter of Book. And I used package `fancyhdr`. And my chapter shows one blank page after `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. But this blank page shows pagenumber on left and contents on right in header. Similarly page after `\listoffigures` shows pagenumber on left and List of Figures on right in Header. How I can make this page completely blank. How I remove this?.

[image: tableofcontent]

want to remove below left pageno. and right Contents
[image: blank]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents` etc. If this does not work, provide a compilable document please!

Comment: Also try \afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}} from the afterpage package.

Comment: Hupfer, Thankx for reply . I tried \thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage after \tableofcontents. But it remove only righthandside text (CONTENTS). But did not remove pagenumber from left. I want to remove Left Pagenumber. And want blank page after Contents.

Comment: @user93268: Then post the document, not just fragments or screenshots

Comment: Here is a link : http://lab.gdy.club/~manpreet9112/DesignAids/main.pdf  . Now I want blank page  after \tableofcontents page,  listoffigures and so on. But , When chapter starts,  I want to display Chaptername on rightside and  pageno. on leftside . As it is displayed on book.

Comment: you can see my pdf on this link: lab.gdy.club/~manpreet9112/DesignAids/main.pdf. Is it correct that, the book class will show  plain page with left pageno and right chapter name in Header, after every contents and List of Figures ?.

Comment: The `pdf` file is not really useful. We need to code to look what is going on

Comment: Hupfer, I found a Best solution to my problem. I used \usepackage{emptypage} in preamble . It remove rightside Contents and leftside pageno from page comes after Table of Contents, List of FIgures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution to problem that I posted. Usually, when we use Book class to create book, it creates blank page with Contents on right-side and  page no. on left-side after Table of Contents page due to fancy header. But we want fancy header on all pages, but don't want to show it on pages that comes after Table of Contents page and List of Figures. Here is a solution. You should use \usepackage{emptypage} in your preamble.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 \usepackage{geometry}
  % total specifies text width and height should not exceed     170mm,257mm.
% right, bottom margins set automatically
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
**\usepackage{emptypage} %remove rightside Contents and Leftside   pageno from page after TableofContents.**
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%====================Macro Definition =====================%
\newcommand{\fig}{Fig.}
\newcommand{\eqn}{Equation}
\newcommand{\chartm}{Chart}
\newcommand{\tablem}{Table}
\newcommand{\fefouronefive}{$Fe$ 415}
\newcommand{\fefivezerozero}{$Fe$ 500}
\newcommand{\fetwofivezero}{$Fe$ 250}
\newcommand{\kn}{kN} 
\newcommand{\knpms}{kN/m^2}
\newcommand{\knm}{kNm}
\newcommand{\mm}{mm}
\newcommand{\npmms}{N/mm^2}
\newcommand{\mms}{mm^2}
\newcommand{\mmspm}{mm^2/m}
\DeclareCaptionType{chart}
\addbibresource{DesignAids.bib}
```